# Google PHP Client: Getting Unauthenticated(401) with refreshed access token

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-client

Following code is working fine with the first access token but after I refresh the access token with refresh token, this throws UNAUTHENTICATED error.

```
    $client = new GoogleClient();
    $client->setClientId('XXXXXX');
    $client->setClientSecret('XXXXX');
    $client->setAccessToken('ya20.xxxxxx);
    $client->refreshToken(1//xxxxxxx);

    $calendarId = 'primary';
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 10,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => date('c'),
    );

    $calendarService = new Calendar($client);
    $results = $calendarService->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
```

I am updating the access token with refresh token in the following way -

```
            $client = new GoogleClient();
            $client->setClientId('XXXXXX');
            $client->setClientSecret('XXXXX');
            $client->setAccessToken('ya20.xxxxxx);

            $newToken = [];
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken('1//xxxx');
            $newTokens = $client->getAccessToken();

            if (isset($newTokens['access_token'])) {
                $accessToken = $newTokens['access_token'];
                $newToken['token'] = $accessToken;
            }

            if (isset($accessToken['refresh_token'])) {
                $refreshToken = $newTokens['refresh_token'];
                $newToken['refresh_token'] = $refreshToken;
            }
```

This is returning the access token but after using this token in the above code I am getting 401 UNAUTHENTICATED Error.

I am fetching access token and refresh token with Laravel/Socialite package

```
        $scopes = [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        ];
        return Socialite::driver('google')
              ->scopes($scopes)
              ->with([
               "access_type" => "offline",
               "prompt" => "consent select_account"])
              ->redirect();
```

Comment: @Ron This is the minimal possible code I could have shown, please suggest a better way. Thanks

Comment: How are you getting your access and refresh token?

Comment: @Genaut: I have updated the question with the code for fetching the access, refresh token

Comment: Where exactly did you get this refresh token?  Was it created via your code?

Answer (score 1):

I would question wither or not your refresh token is valid.

This is the method i use.

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

## validate refresh token

To use a refresh token is a HTTP Post call.  If the call isnt working with php it would sugest to me that this is not a valid.

If You want to try and validate it directly using something like postman the call would be like this.

```
HTTP POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: How can I check the validity of refresh token?
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?refresh_token=refreshToken, this doesn't work

Comment: Check update the second like is the post body.